# Is it possible to use kombu as client library for activeMQ?

Tags: python, activemq-classic, amqp, kombu

Trying to switch from rabbitMQ to activeMQ keeping kombu library but my script just hang on. Does kombu supports activeMQ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of anyone using it with ActiveMQ but given it is seemingly designed for Rabbit I'd guess not as Rabbit is not based on an official AMQP version but the draft AMQP 0.9 versions.  ActiveMQ implements AMQP v1.0 which is the official AMQP version an so that library would need to implement that in order to be compatible.

The Apache Qpid project supplies a number of clients that can be used against ActiveMQ